# Getting Errors running Valgrind with SDL2 code

Tags: c, ubuntu-14.04, sdl-2, video-card

I am starting to learn SDL, and I am following some tutorials on internet. 
I wrote a simple code that shows the window for 2 seconds on screen:

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define SCREEN_WIDTH 640
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT 480

int main(void)
{
    SDL_Window* window = NULL;
    SDL_Surface* screenSurface = NULL;

    if( SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_VIDEO ) < 0 )
    {
        printf( "SDL could not initialize! SDL_Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError() );
    }
    else
    {
        window = SDL_CreateWindow( "SDL Tutorial", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN );
        if( window == NULL )
        {
            printf( "Window could not be created! SDL_Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError() );
        }
        else
        {
            screenSurface = SDL_GetWindowSurface( window );
            SDL_FillRect( screenSurface, NULL, SDL_MapRGB( screenSurface->format, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF ) );
            SDL_UpdateWindowSurface( window );
            SDL_Delay( 2000 );
        }
    }

    SDL_DestroyWindow( window );
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

When I run it, it works well. But if I run it with `Valgrind`, many invalid read and other errors are shown. To see the errors see [here](http://pastebin.com/Gawkw4Uf)

All of them it seems to be related with `fglrx_dri.so`.

The long story is:
I recently bought a Dell laptop with Ubuntu 14.04 and with a AMD graphics video card. I could not install it. I tried a lot of ways to install it but failed. So when I type on terminal `lspci | grep VGA` shows:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics (rev 09)
```

So I am using my integrated graphics. (and not my AMD graphic video card)

When I type on terminal `fglrxinfo`:

```
display: :0  screen: 0
OpenGL vendor string: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: AMD Radeon R7 M260
OpenGL version string: 4.4.13374 Compatibility Profile Context 15.20.1013
```

And according to [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/AMD) in section 3, my AMD graphics video card is installed and working. (But it isn't).

So, back to my SDL problem, when I was running my first SDL program, 
an error `libGL error: dlopen /usr/lib/fglrx/dri/i965_dri.so failed (/usr/lib/fglrx/dri/i965_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)` was shown. I opend [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34215617/error-running-simple-code-sdl) question, but I can't solve it. So I copyed the file `i965_dri.so` to directory `/usr/lib/fglrx/dri/`. This makes this error disappear.

So, anyone has an idea why this is occurring ? I really want to put my graphic video card to work. But after many many attempt, I forgot my graphic video card and just want to make my SDL code work well without errors or memory leak.

Thanks !

Comment: I don't think your valgrind results related to driver problems, although it may be, but general rule is not every code piece is very good, and if authors never used valgrind and didn't fixed detected problems - you're out of luck and will either have to live with that or blacklist this entries so valgrind woudln't report them again.

Comment: I found [this](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/dist.readme-missing.html). Will solve just the first error, or perhaps all of them.

Comment: On the second thought, it might not be an error at all but memory valgrind don't know about, e.g. virtualised GPU memory.